# Getting an error TS1056 when using typescript with cypress

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cypress

I am getting the error:

```
Error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher
```

I use typescript, cucumber and cypress.
This is my demo project:
https://github.com/mareru/cypress-cucumber-example/tree/typscript-support

I googled the error and did all the recommended things in `tsconfig.json` file but nothing seem to help.
Please checkout the project and help to resolve this error.
I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.
Please help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: `tsconfig.json` is supposed to be in the root of your project

Comment: Omg thanks man that was the failure from my side. I feel so stupid :D Please answer it so I can give you credit :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `tsconfig.json` file to the root of you project so that cypress will pick up on it.